# Python OO -- class member has NoneType

Tags: python, oop, class, attributes, instance

I am turning some piece of Python code into OO-code. I define a class and a two arguments constructor.

```
class myclass:
     MAX=5000
     FTOL = 10**(-10)
     TINY = 10**(-10)
     def __init__(self, initPt_,fun_):
         self.initPt = initPt_
         self.fun = fun_
```

With this code, I expect initPt and fun to be class members. I execute the code and write this instanciation in shell:

```
x=myclass([1,1],Optim.fun1)
```

where fun1 is a function defined in module Optim, that I accurately imported.

I added to myclass a function:

```
def build(self):
    self.initPt=self.initPt.append(self.fun(self.initPt))
    s=[self.initPt]
    for k in range(len(self.initPt)):
        temp=[x for x in self.initPt]
        temp[k]=self.initPt[k]+1
        s.append(temp)
    return s
```

I call method build on the instance x I just created. This error appears:

```
for k in range(len(self.initPt)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

and indeed, if I add this test line in code:

```
print str(type(self.iniPt))
```

shell indicates that type is NoneType, althought I instanciated x with self.initPt = [1,1].

Moreover, if I write x.initPt in shell, result is accurate: [1,1,0.2] (after call of method build, third value is added to initial list [1,1]).

I don't understand why it is not resolving type dynamically. It is not object programming then. What should I do?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Just one tiny bit of idiomatic improvement: `temp = self.initPt[:]; temp[k] += 1`. And a hint: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is at least part of your problem:

```
self.initPt=self.initPt.append(self.fun(self.initPt))
```

Using the `append` method of a list modifies the list in place and returns `None`. So this replaces the list assigned to `self.initPt` with `None`. Just do this:

```
self.initPt.append(self.fun(self.initPt))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
self.initPt=self.initPt.append(self.fun(self.initPt))
```

Right here you wiped out your list and replaced it with `None`. `append()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ... have a tough time following your intentions, but the trouble is in this line:

```
self.initPt=self.initPt.append(self.fun(self.initPt))
```

You're attempting to assign the return value of `self.initPt.append` to `self.initPt`.  The `append()` method of a list adds a value to the list, but returns None.  You've lost `self.initPt`.